# How to fill a column based on another column truth value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df (car_data) where there are 2 columns: model and is_4wd.

The is_4wd is either 0 or 1 and have about 25,000 missing values. However, I know that some models are 4wd because they already has a 1, and the same models have nan.

How can I replace the nan values for the models I know they already 1?

I have created a for loop, but I had to change all nan values to 0, create a variable of unique car models and the loop take a long time to complete.

```
car_data['is_4wd']=car_data['is_4wd'].fillna(0)
car_4wd=car_data.query('is_4wd==1')
caru=car_4wd['model'].unique()
for index, row in car_data.iterrows():
    if row['is_4wd']==0:
        if row['model'] in caru:
            car_data.loc[car_data.model==row['model'],'is_4wd']=1
```

Is there a better way to do it? Tried several replace() methods but to no avail.

The df head looks like this: (you can see ford f-150 for example has both 1 and nan in is_4wd) the expected outcome is to replace all the nan for the models I know they have values already entered with 1.

```
   price  model_year           model  condition  cylinders fuel  odometer  \
0   9400      2011.0          bmw x5       good        6.0  gas  145000.0   
1  25500         NaN      ford f-150       good        6.0  gas   88705.0   
2   5500      2013.0  hyundai sonata   like new        4.0  gas  110000.0   
3   1500      2003.0      ford f-150       fair        8.0  gas       NaN   
4  14900      2017.0    chrysler 200  excellent        4.0  gas   80903.0   

  transmission    type paint_color  is_4wd date_posted  days_listed  
0    automatic     SUV         NaN     1.0  2018-06-23           19  
1    automatic  pickup       white     1.0  2018-10-19           50  
2    automatic   sedan         red     NaN  2019-02-07           79  
3    automatic  pickup         NaN     NaN  2019-03-22            9  
4    automatic   sedan       black     NaN  2019-04-02           28
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data, along with the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data by `model` column and fill `is_4wd` column by the max value of the group:

```
df['is_4wd'] = df.groupby('model')['is_4wd'] \
                 .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max())).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df[['model', 'is_4wd']])

# Output:
            model  is_4wd
0          bmw x5       1
1      ford f-150       1
2  hyundai sonata       0
3      ford f-150       1
4    chrysler 200       0
```

Comment: Works! You are a master of pandas;)

Comment: Just for learning purposes, if I wanted to take into consideration the model_year column in addition to model column, and then decide if 1 should be entered under is_4wd, how should I have done that?

Comment: Just add `model_year` to `groupby`: `df.groupby(['model', 'model_year'])`